# PHP&JS Encrypt/sign and validate QR Code

Tags: javascript, php, security, hash, public-key-encryption

I have a php script that generates a [QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). This code will be read from a PhoneGap app in JavaScript. This works fine so far but I would like to secure the QR Code so none else can generate other valid codes.

My first thought was to add a hash of the data in the QR Code. but common hash functions are not very secure. For good hash functions I did not find a implementation for JavaScript. Second thought was to use public/private key encryption but here again is JavaScript a problem.

Another huge problem is that the QR Code should be simple. A long encryption will make the small QR Code unreadable.

What would be a good approach to secure a QR Code?

Comment: If you're generating and testing the code in PHP, why do you care about hashing or encryption in the javascript space?

Comment: step back and stop thinking in terms of QR codes - that's just a graphical representation of some data that happens to be readable by various scanners. They're still just normal data like any other data. start thinking about encrypting your data string and ONLY about encrypting your string. the QR code is simply one way of presenting it.

Comment: @MarcB Well, I know it is just data. But those details create limitations I cannot ignore. Otherwise I would just use PGP. Sure I can run PGP in JavaScript but the encrypted data is just to big.

Comment: What kind of data is in the qr code? Does it really need to be secured?

Comment: @zerkms Data is an integer ID of a container. No one will die if it is not secure but it would be nicer if not anyone can fake IDs as he likes to.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: what if instead of encrypting you just use not-guessable IDs?

Comment: @zerms True, thanks. I think that would be sufficient. You can still copy the code but you can do that anyway. I will do that. You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Instead of using the ID just (if you are using database) add another column with some "random" unique generated string. That way no one can figure out your sequence.
I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hash using a shared secret to your ID like this:

```
$qrcontent = $id . md5($id . $secret);
```

So to create a new `$qrcontent` one needs to know the `$secret`. There are some simple hashes like crc32 so you don't need a fully implemented javascript md5 function for example. You can define how long / secure your hash should be.

Comment: [md5](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)? [MD5](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996)? Seriously? SHA1 is not much better, but bcypt is.

Comment: My answer is not about selecting the ideal hash function (wich always depends on use case) but applying them to a problem. I think even using a short, broken hash function with a secret is still multitudes better than many other solutions, changing the hash function is simple.

Comment: Yes, sure. :) I did not mean to sound that rude. I also thought about adding a hash.